# horizontal center div's with a absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs inside a section. The divs position is absolute because I want a really small gap between the 3 divs, but when I want to horizontal the divs nothing happens. What should I do?

```css
#columnL {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#columnM {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#columnR {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="blabla">
  <div id="columnL">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="columnM">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="columnR">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @j08691 when i do relative and I look at the website on an other device the images will overlap

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent div with a **relative** positioning rule. Like this:

```
#blabla {
  position: relative;
}
```

Indicate the `margin: auto` for each card - `#columnL`, `#columnM` and `#columnR`.

And push the `width: 100%` for the `img` tag. Like this:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

But why do you need **absolute** positioning?

```css
#blabla {
  position: relative;
}

#columnL {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#columnM {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}

#columnR {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="blabla">
  <div id="columnL">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="columnM">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="columnR">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Solution with **flex** and **absolute** positioning.

The absolute in this solution is an additional parent block, with a class of `.absolute`, as well as a flexible rule that sets the indentation by the `gap` rule.

```css
#blabla {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 30px;
}

#columnL {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
}

#columnM {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
}

#columnR {
  width: 412px;
  height: 705px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="blabla">
 <div class="absolute">
  <div id="columnL">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="columnM">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="columnR">
    <div id="afbeeldingL">
      <img src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/110-14018-b-Petronas-V2017.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tekstL">
      <h1 id="hoofdstuk1">TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i want to make a small gap between the 3 images. i could do that with relative because the images will overlap on a other screen.. what would you recomend?

Comment: @Tim, I gave you the second solution (second snippet) + description. This solution is indented with a gap rule. And if you need absolute positioning, then I made another parent block with absolute positioning.